# Multiple ttyACM device instances - is this

Tags: linux, serial-port, uart, archlinux

Why does `dmesg | grep acm` give me multiple instances of ttyACM0 ?
I do not have any serial device connected to 'ttyACM2' - why is it in the list?

```
[    6.075663] cdc_acm 3-4.1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[    6.088262] cdc_acm 3-4.1.3:1.0: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[    6.088935] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[    6.088937] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[   81.979767] cdc_acm 3-4.1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  117.307776] cdc_acm 3-4.1.1:1.0: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
[ 2126.911886] cdc_acm 3-4.1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 2139.455925] cdc_acm 3-4.1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 2227.775910] cdc_acm 3-4.1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 2265.151729] cdc_acm 3-4.1.1:1.0: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
[62661.970060] cdc_acm 3-4.1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[62674.513699] cdc_acm 3-4.1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[62847.569753] cdc_acm 3-4.1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[62888.785759] cdc_acm 3-4.1.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Comment: You will want to look at the surrounding context (`grep` has an option to include *n* lines of context)... most likely you will see USB disconnect/reconnect cycles

Comment: That said, this sort of question is not unique to programming (any Linux user with a USB/serial converter could have this question) and belongs on either unix.stackexchange.com or superuser